Undefined control sequence \csvautotabularray
I want to display a csv file in a more presentable way, so I tried to use the csvsimple package. However, when I run the following code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weißbäck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
Bauer,Maria,19202,f,3.3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \csvautotabularray{grade.csv}
\end{document}

I get the following error message:
marks.tex: error: 14: Undefined control sequence. \csvautotabularray

What is the source of this error? And how can I fix it? Thank you very much.
Edit: I am adding the log file as per the comment's request.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Fedora 40) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.5.25)  13 JUN 2024 14:54
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**marks.tex
(./marks.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabularray/tabularray.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2023-02-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-01-16 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
))
Package: tabularray 2023-03-01 v2023A Typeset tabulars and arrays with LaTeX3
\l__tblr_a_int=\count194
\l__tblr_c_int=\count195
\l__tblr_r_int=\count196
\l__tblr_d_dim=\dimen141
\l__tblr_h_dim=\dimen142
\l__tblr_o_dim=\dimen143
\l__tblr_p_dim=\dimen144
\l__tblr_q_dim=\dimen145
\l__tblr_r_dim=\dimen146
\l__tblr_s_dim=\dimen147
\l__tblr_t_dim=\dimen148
\l__tblr_v_dim=\dimen149
\l__tblr_w_dim=\dimen150
\l__tblr_a_box=\box52
\l__tblr_b_box=\box53
\l__tblr_c_box=\box54
\l__tblr_d_box=\box55
\g__tblr_table_count_int=\count197
\c@rownum=\count198
\c@colnum=\count199
\c@rowcount=\count266
\c@colcount=\count267
\abovesep=\dimen151
\belowsep=\dimen152
\leftsep=\dimen153
\rightsep=\dimen154
\g_tblr_level_int=\count268
\g__tblr_data_row_key_count_int=\count269
\g__tblr_data_column_key_count_int=\count270
\g__tblr_data_cell_key_count_int=\count271
\g__tblr_array_int=\count272
\l__tblr_key_count_int=\count273
\l__tblr_key_quotient_int=\count274
\l__tblr_key_quotient_two_int=\count275
\l__tblr_key_remainder_int=\count276
\g__tblr_data_str_value_count_int=\count277
\rulewidth=\dimen155
\l__tblr_strut_dp_dim=\dimen156
\l__tblr_strut_ht_dim=\dimen157
\g__tblr_cell_wd_dim=\dimen158
\g__tblr_cell_ht_dim=\dimen159
\g__tblr_cell_head_dim=\dimen160
\g__tblr_cell_foot_dim=\dimen161
\l__column_target_dim=\dimen162
\l__tblr_caption_box=\box56
\l__tblr_caption_left_box=\box57
\l__tblr_row_head_box=\box58
\l__tblr_row_foot_box=\box59
\l__tblr_row_head_foot_dim=\dimen163
\tablewidth=\dimen164
\l__tblr_table_firsthead_box=\box60
\l__tblr_table_middlehead_box=\box61
\l__tblr_table_lasthead_box=\box62
\l__tblr_table_firstfoot_box=\box63
\l__tblr_table_middlefoot_box=\box64
\l__tblr_table_lastfoot_box=\box65
\l__tblr_remain_height_dim=\dimen165
\l__tblr_long_from_int=\count278
\l__tblr_long_to_int=\count279
\l__tblr_curr_i_int=\count280
\l__tblr_prev_i_int=\count281
\l__tblr_table_page_int=\count282
\l__tblr_table_head_box=\box66
\l__tblr_table_foot_box=\box67
\l__tblr_table_head_foot_dim=\dimen166
\l__tblr_table_head_body_foot_dim=\dimen167
\l__tblr_table_box=\box68
\l__tblr_table_hlines_box=\box69
\l__tblr_hline_box=\box70
\l__tblr_row_box=\box71
\l__tblr_col_o_wd_dim=\dimen168
\l__tblr_col_b_wd_dim=\dimen169
\l__tblr_hline_leftskip_dim=\dimen170
\l__tblr_hline_rightskip_dim=\dimen171
\l__tblr_row_ht_dim=\dimen172
\l__tblr_row_dp_dim=\dimen173
\l__tblr_row_abovesep_dim=\dimen174
\l__tblr_row_belowsep_dim=\dimen175
\l__tblr_row_vlines_box=\box72
\l__tblr_vline_box=\box73
\l__tblr_cell_box=\box74
\l__row_upper_dim=\dimen176
\l__row_lower_dim=\dimen177
\l__row_vpace_dim=\dimen178
\l__tblr_vline_aboveskip_dim=\dimen179
\l__tblr_vline_belowskip_dim=\dimen180
\l__tblr_cell_wd_dim=\dimen181
\l__tblr_cell_ht_dim=\dimen182
\l__tblr_diag_box=\box75
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csvsimple/csvsimple-l3.sty
Package: csvsimple-l3 2022/09/20 v2.3.2 LaTeX3 CSV file processing
\g__csvsim_col_int=\count283
\g__csvsim_colmax_int=\count284
\g_csvsim_inputline_int=\count285
\g_csvsim_row_int=\count286
\g_csvsim_columncount_int=\count287
)

LaTeX Info: File `grade.csv' already exists on the system.
            Not generating it from this source.

(./marks.aux)
\openout1 = `marks.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.14    \csvautotabularray
                        {grade.csv}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./marks.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2719 strings out of 477926
 67737 string characters out of 5837434
 1849388 words of memory out of 6000000
 22999 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 512287 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 34 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 58i,5n,63p,217b,322s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/share
/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on marks.pdf (1 page, 12942 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

Edit 2: The same error message appears when running the code in Overleaf.


Can you show your .log file so we can see which package versions you have?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added the log file.

Can you update? It compiles fine for me with an up-to-date texlive 2024 including csvsimple-l3 v2.6.1

I will update texlive and try run gain. The problem is, the error occurs even in Overleaf.

Overleaf uses an old texlive from summer 2023, but the macro you want to use was only added in 2023-10-13.

Alright, I will update texlive and run the code again and see.
